# IncompleteRead error when submitting neo4j batch from remote server; malformed HTTP response

Tags: http, neo4j, tcpdump, py2neo

I've set up neo4j on server A, and I have an app running on server B which is to connect to it.

If I clone the app on server A and run the unit tests, it works fine. But running them on server B, the setup runs for 30 seconds and fails with an IncompleteRead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/nose/suite.py", line 208, in run
    self.setUp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/nose/suite.py", line 291, in setUp
    self.setupContext(ancestor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/nose/suite.py", line 314, in setupContext
    try_run(context, names)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/nose/util.py", line 469, in try_run
    return func()
  File "/comps/comps/webapp/tests/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    create_graph.import_films(films)
  File "/comps/comps/create_graph.py", line 49, in import_films
    batch.submit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo-1.6.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/py2neo/neo4j.py", line 2643, in submit
    return [BatchResponse(rs).hydrated for rs in responses.json]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo-1.6.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/py2neo/packages/httpstream/http.py", line 563, in json
    return json.loads(self.read().decode(self.encoding))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo-1.6.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/py2neo/packages/httpstream/http.py", line 634, in read
    data = self._response.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 532, in read
    return self._read_chunked(amt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 575, in _read_chunked
    raise IncompleteRead(''.join(value))
IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(131072 bytes read)
-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------
py2neo.neo4j.batch: INFO: Executing batch with 2 requests
py2neo.neo4j.batch: INFO: Executing batch with 1800 requests
--------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------
```

The exception happens when I submit a sufficiently large batch. If I reduce the size of the data set, it goes away. It seems to be related to request size rather than the number of requests (if I add properties to the nodes I'm creating, I can have fewer requests).

If I use `batch.run()` instead of `.submit()`, I don't get an error, but the tests fail; it seems that the batch is rejected silently. If I use `.stream()` and don't iterate over the results, the same thing happens as `.run()`; if I do iterate over them, I get the same error as `.submit()` (except that it's "0 bytes read").

Looking at httplib.py suggests that we'll get this error when an HTTP response has `Transfer-Encoding: Chunked` and doesn't contain a chunk size where one is expected. So I ran tcpdump over the tests, and indeed, that seems to be what's happening. The final chunk has length `0x8000`, and its final bytes are

```
"http://10.210.\r\n
0\r\n
\r\n
```

(Linebreaks added after \n for clarity.) This looks like correct chunking, but the 0x8000th byte is the first "/", rather than the second ".". Eight bytes early. It also isn't a complete response, being invalid JSON.

Interestingly, within this chunk we get the following data:

```
"all_relatio\r\n
1280\r\n
nships":
```

That is, it looks like the start of a new chunk, but embedded within the old one. This new chunk would finish in the correct location (the second "." of above), if we noticed it starting. And if the chunk header wasn't there, the old chunk would finish in the correct location (eight bytes later).

I then extracted the POST request of the batch, and ran it using `cat batch-request.txt | nc $SERVER_A 7474`. The response to that was a valid chunked HTTP response, containing a complete valid JSON object.

I thought maybe netcat was sending the request faster than py2neo, so I introduced some slowdown

```
cat batch-request.txt | perl -ne 'BEGIN { $| = 1 } for (split //) { select(undef, undef, undef, 0.1) unless int(rand(50)); print }' | nc $SERVER_A 7474
```

But it continued to work, despite being much slower now.

I also tried doing tcpdump on server A, but requests to localhost don't go over tcp.

I still have a few avenues that I haven't explored: I haven't worked out how reliably the request fails or under precisely which conditions (I once saw it succeed with a batch that usually fails, but I haven't explored the boundaries). And I haven't tried making the request from python directly, without going through py2neo. But I don't particularly expect either of these to be be very informative. And I haven't looked closely at the TCP dump except for using wireshark's 'follow TCP stream' to extract the HTTP conversation; I don't really know what I'd be looking for there. There's a large section that wireshark highlights in black in the failed dump, and only isolated lines black in the successful dump, maybe that's relevant?

So for now: does anyone know what might be going on? Anything else I should try to diagnose the problem?

The TCP dumps are here: [failed](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6801095/dump-py2neo-fail.pcap) and [successful](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6801095/dump-py2neo-fail.pcap).

**EDIT:** I'm starting to understand the failed TCP dump. The whole conversation takes ~30 seconds, and there's a ~28-second gap in which both servers are sending ZeroWindow TCP frames - these are the black lines I mentioned.

First, py2neo fills up neo4j's window; neo4j sends a frame saying "my window is full", and then another frame which fills up py2neo's window. Then we spend ~28 seconds with each of them just saying "yup, my window is still full". Eventually neo4j opens its window again, py2neo sends a bit more data, and then py2neo opens *its* window. Both of them send a bit more data, then py2neo finishes sending its request, and neo4j sends more data before also finishing.

So I'm thinking that maybe the problem is something like, both of them are refusing to process more data until they've sent some more, and neither can send some more until the other processes some. Eventually neo4j enters a "something's gone wrong" loop, which py2neo interprets as "go ahead and send more data".

It's interesting, but I'm not sure what it means, that the penultimate TCP frame sent from neo4j to py2neo starts `\r\n1280\r\n` - the beginning of the fake-chunk. The `\r\n8000\r\n` that starts the actual chunk, just appears part-way through an unremarkable TCP frame. (It was the third frame sent after py2neo finished sending its post request.)

**EDIT 2:** I checked to see precisely where python was hanging. Unsurprisingly, it was while sending the request - so `BatchRequestList._execute()` doesn't return until after neo4j gives up, which is why neither `.run()` or `.stream()` did any better than `.submit()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that a workaround is to set the header `X-Stream: true;format=pretty`. (By default it's just `true`; it *used* to be pretty, but that was removed due to [this bug](https://github.com/nigelsmall/py2neo/issues/204) (which looks like it's actually a neo4j bug, and still seems to be open, but isn't currently an issue for me).

It looks like, by setting `format=pretty`, we cause neo4j to not send any data until it's processed the whole of the input. So it doesn't try to send data, doesn't block while sending, and doesn't refuse to read until it's sent something.

Removing the `X-Stream` header entirely, or setting it to `false`, seems to have the same effect as setting `format=pretty` (as in, making neo4j send a response which is chunked, pretty-printed, doesn't contain status codes, and doesn't get sent until the whole request has been processed), which is kinda weird.

You can set the header for an individual batch with

```
batch._batch._headers['X-Stream'] = 'true;format=pretty'
```

Or set the global headers with

```
neo4j._add_header('X-Stream', 'true;format=pretty')
```